# Prove that this function has derivatives of all orders in some neighborhood of zero: $\sqrt{\frac{t}{\log\frac{1}{2e^{-t}-1}}}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, complex-analysis, derivatives

I want to prove that the following real function has derivatives of all orders in some neighborhood of zero:
$$f(t)=\sqrt{\frac{t}{\log\frac{1}{2e^{-t}-1}}}.$$
Moreover, there exists a constant $C$ such that $|f^{(k)}(0)|\leq C$ for all $k\geq 0.$
I conjecture that $f$ is analytic in some open interval $(-a,a)$ but am not entirely sure.

Edits: If the question regarding $C$ does not have positive answer, then can we show that $|f^{(k)}(0)|\leq 2^{\mathcal{O}(k)}$ as $k\to\infty$?

Comment: I've met it [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3930572). Just see that $f^{-2}(t)$ is analytic in a nbhd of $0$, hence (since $f(0)>0$ in the limit) both $f^2(t)$ and $f(t)$ are. The statement regarding $C$ doesn't hold, because otherwise $f(t)$ would be entire.

Comment: What do you mean by $f^{-2}(t)$ ? I am a bit confused by the negative power $-2$. Can you please provide a more detailed answer below, since I'm not sure that I understand how your previous post could help to answer the above question. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, i see. But your comment regarding C is not so clear. as far as i know, if $f$ has uniformly bounded derivatives on any compact interval, then $f$ will be entire. But the question here is only about derivatives at 0.

Comment: I think the domain of $f$ is $(-\infty, \log 2)$, thus it is not entire, right? By the way, I am considering only real functions.

Comment: @metamorphy: I just make a small edit in the problem statement regarding your comment about $C$. Apparently, the rate of $|f^{(k)}(0)|$ is related to showing that your expression $S_n$ [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3930413/calculating-sum-k-0n-n-choose-k-sqrtk/3930572#3930572) admits an asymptotic scaling $S_n=2^n\sqrt{\frac{2}{n}}(1-\mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{n})\right).$

Comment: Well, the radius of convergence of $\sum_{k=0}^\infty f^{(k)}(0)t^k/k!$ *(a side note: I don't want to "stay real", it makes a pain in the...)* is equal to the distance to a closest singularity, in our case it is at $t=\log 2$. Thus, if $r>\log 2$, then $f^{(k)}(0)r^k/k!$ cannot tend to zero, hence $f^{(k)}(0)$ has at least a factorial-like growth.

Comment: @metamorphy: That makes sense. But can you still show that $S_n$ has the above asymptotic behavior? Or more generally, I wonder if the following is true for your expansion: $S_n=2^n\sqrt{\frac{2}{n}}(1-o(1))$ as $n\to\infty$

Comment: I think I've done it in that answer. ($\sqrt{\color{red}{2/n}}$ is wrong BTW.)

Answer (score 0):

*This is probably a stupid answer.*

In the real domain, the function
$$f(t)=\sqrt{\frac{t}{\log \left(\frac{1}{2 e^{-t}-1}\right)}}$$ exists as long as
$$-t \log \left(2 e^{-t}-1\right)\geq 0\implies t \leq \log(2)$$ So, as you wrote in comments, the domain is $(-\infty, \log (2))$.

Composing Taylor series around $t=0$
$$f(t)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\Big[1-\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac {a_n} {n!} \,t^n\Big]$$ where the $a_n$ make the sequence
$$\left\{\frac{1}{4},\frac{5}{16},\frac{47}{64},\frac{711}{256},\frac{44851}{3072},\frac
  {401661}{4096},\frac{13128607}{16384},\frac{1516267757}{196608},\cdots\right\}$$

Comment: What you wrote is correct. But my question is how to bound $a_n$.

Comment: @M-Brust. I know that but ... I am stuck !

Comment: I wonder if the kind of argument of @robjohn from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/332142/looking-for-help-with-a-proof-that-n-th-derivative-of-e-frac-1x2-0-for?noredirect=1&lq=1) can be used, namely if the derivatives have some structure that can be exploited.

Comment: It hink that $0$ is simpler but I shall work the problem. If you get any answer, please, ping me here. I am curious to see it. Cheers :-)

Comment: Btw, it seems to me that in your expression you have $-a_n=f^{(n)}(0)\leq 0$ for all $n.$ Did you manage to show this (analytically) or is it a guess?

Comment: @M-Brust. This comes to the fact that all coefficients of the expansion of $\frac{1}{2 e^{-t}-1}$ are positive.